# Java: Annoying JTextPane border, how to remove it?

Tags: java, swing

I have JTextPane as in picture:
[image]

The border name is view_desc 
I tried following things:

```
view_desc.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
//and
view_desc.setBorder(null);
```

But it's still there, how can I remove it?

Comment: I've just tested it and `BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder()` does the trick for me. Are you sure it isn't working? Maybe post a little more context.

Comment: Q: Are you sure the problem is actually JTextPane?  For example: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?482012-JTextArea-line-%28not-border%29-around-rect.  If you're using an IDE (like NetBeans), make sure there aren't any other controls being inadvertently created behind you back...

Comment: Got it, turns out JTextPane once created using Netbeans drag'n'drop it also creates JScrollPane as parent for it. So it was border of ScrollPane instead of TextPane

Comment: instead of setting an empty border just set the function to null.  view_desc.setBorder(null);

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Netbeans, just go to Other Components - Navigator on your left side of the screen. Click JScrollPane where JTextPane is located and remove the border in the Properties.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works fine for `JScrollPane` :

```
scrollPane.setViewportBorder(null);
scrollPane.setBorder(null);
```